# How to get a question flagged without enough reputation to do so?

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicate-questions

The question [sum count column in raster attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107106/sum-count-column-in-raster-attribute) seems to be a duplicate of [count attribute in raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107138/count-attribute-in-raster).

They're both from the same user and the user seem to be confused and asked the question in a slightly different form a few hours later. Both questions have answers. My reputation is too low, I don't get a flag option on the question, I don't know how or to whom to draw attention to the questions.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for bringing that to our attention. I have marked the second question as a duplicate. As you indicated, you need 15 reputation ([source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)) to start flagging questions. This is to ensure that users have the sufficient experience to properly flag a question and not generate undue noise for reviewers.